# How to change dynamically redirect Url Socialite in Controller Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, facebook

Because my web app has 2 separate logins, but both want to use the Facebook login methods, but there is a problem when I want to callback to 2 different controllers but that doesn't work.

config file .env

```
FACEBOOK_APP_LOGIN_CALLBACK_URL=http://localhost/auth/callback/facebook
FACEBOOK_APP_LOGIN_CALLBACK_URL_CLIENT=http://localhost/client/auth/callback/facebook
```

config file services.php

```
'facebook' => [
        'client_id' => env('FACEBOOK_APP_LOGIN_ID'),
        'client_secret' => env('FACEBOOK_APP_LOGIN_SECRET'),
        'redirect' => env('FACEBOOK_APP_LOGIN_CALLBACK_URL'),
    ],
```

By default when logging in `http://localhost/auth/callback/facebook` will be used, it works fine.
But in the second login method I want to change the redirect URL to `http://localhost/client/auth/callback/facebook` in the Controller, in Controller I did like this but did not work

```
public function redirectToProvider($social) {
        $redirectUrl = "http://localhost/client/auth/callback/facebook";
        return Socialite::driver($social)->redirectUrl($redirectUrl)->redirect();
    }
```

Facebook has returned an error:

```
Client error: `POST https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token` resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response: { "error": "invalid_grant", "error_description": "Malformed auth code." }
```

How to change the Url redirect dynamically?
Thanks everyone!